# Creating logfile from application console with .bat and executing next line of script

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I currently have the following .bat script:

```
acServer.exe %* > console.log
timeout 30 /nobreak
stracker.exe --stracker_ini stracker.ini
```

But it only executes the first line, so it never starts the 2nd application.

I need a script that first starts the acServer.exe application and logs its console output to console.log
While acserver.exe is still running and being logged it should start the stracker.exe application (about 30 seconds after acserver.exe was started.)

*EDIT - Based on comments to SomethingDard's answer, the OP also wants to kill the acServer.exe process when the batch script ends.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch files run one command at a time, so the script waits until acServer.exe ends before continuing... unless you use the `start` command.

```
start "" acServer.exe %* > console.log
timeout 30 /nobreak
stracker.exe --stracker_ini stracker.ini
```

Comment: Perfect that works, how can I make it close the acServer.exe application when the batch script is closed? (and only the instance of acServer.exe that was started by this script)

And what does the "" do after the start command?

Comment: `start` considers the first set of double quotes it encounters to be the window title, which runs the risk of breaking your code. The `""` gets the first set of quotes out of the way in case the path to acServer.exe has spaces that you need to wrap in quotes. If you're looking for an event listener to monitor the status of the script, batch doesn't really have anything like that without writing a second script to monitor the first one.

Comment: I'm not looking for an event listener, I just want both applications to be closed when I end/close the script.

Would that be possible?

Comment: You can run `taskkill /IM acServer.exe` to kill the acserver process.

Comment: Yes, but that would kill all processes with that name.
I only want the one killed that is started by this batch file. (since there will be multiple instances of this batch running)

Comment: I suppose you could take a baseline list of PIDs from `tasklist` before you ran acServer, re-run tasklist, search for the new acServer PID and then  use `taskkill /PID <pid>` to kill that specific process.

Comment: I just found out that when I run it with: start "" acServer.exe %* > console.log

That the console.log no longer contains the applications console output.